# Building OpenSSH on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, openssh

I'm trying to build OpenSSH 5.1 on Cygwin.  I'm using the following configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --libexecdir='${sbindir}' \
--localstatedir=/var --datadir='${prefix}/share' --mandir='${datadir}/man' \
--infodir='${datadir}/info'
```

The configure command runs OK, but when I try to make I get this error:

```
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -fno-builtin-memset  -I. -I.. -I. -
..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -c bsd-arc4random.c
In file included from ../openbsd-compat/openbsd-compat.h:45,
                 from ../includes.h:169,
                 from bsd-arc4random.c:17:
../openbsd-compat/getrrsetbyname.h:57:26: arpa/nameser.h: No such file or directory
../openbsd-compat/getrrsetbyname.h:59:20: resolv.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm a bit stuck.  Anyone got any ideas.

Comment: Why are you trying to build OpenSSH yourself?  It's available for Cygwin already.  If you just did a default install, it won't be present because it isn't installed by default, but you can just re-run setup.exe and select it.  It's in the Net category.

Comment: If you just need OpenSSH 5.1, instead of the current 5.2, you must be using Cygwin 1.7.  If you roll back to Cygwin 1.5, you'll get OpenSSH 5.1.

By the way, I just built OpenSSH 5.2 with the command you gave above and it builds without problems.

Answer (score 2):

The particular problem in this build was that the Cygwin system didn't have the minires package installed. You should have first installed minires (1.02 or smth) which installs the necessary arpa/nameser*.h and resolv.h files in the appropriate places (/usr/local/include or /usr/include).

Answer (score -2):

Openssh is available in Cygwin. Just use that.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to change something in the source-code.  Anyway, I gave up and found another solution, so I really should have removed this question.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Darn, I can't remember now.  I think I was trying to emulate a bug in another SSH server by changing the source-code in OpenSSH to match the other server's behavior. I think I just took a step back and solved the problem without attempting the emulation.